# Undefined Returns on JSON Strings

Tags: javascript, json

I was wondering if anyone was able to explain why All of my JSON is returning as Undefined.. The json is question is this

```
{"273746":[{"name":"Darius's Wizards","tier":"GOLD","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"273746","playerOrTeamName":"Magnanimous","division":"V","leaguePoints":0,"wins":19,"losses":15,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}]}]}
```

and the Javascript i've got to run through this is:

Note: in the code provided i /sumID is 273746 and s is 'oce' due to Riot API guidelines i can't give you a direct link to the API so i had to paste it in above.

function statsLookUp(i,s) {

```
    $.ajax({

    url: 'https://oce.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + s + '/v2.5/league/by-summoner/' + i + '/entry?api_key=',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
     success: function (json) {
        //all json goes here

        var sumID = i;

        leagueName = json[sumID].name;
        leagueTier = json[sumID].tier;
        leagueDiv = json[sumID].entries.division;
        leagueLoss = json[sumID].entries.losses;
        leagueWin = json[sumID].entries.wins;


           document.getElementById("sLeague").innerHTML = leagueName;
           document.getElementById("sTier").innerHTML = leagueTier;
           document.getElementById("sDivision").innerHTML = leagueDiv;
           document.getElementById("sWins").innerHTML = leagueWin;
           document.getElementById("sLosses").innerHTML = leagueLoss;


        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error getting Summoner data!");
        }
    });
}
```

everything continues to return as undefined, but i can't seem to find the issue at hand :/

Comment: `json[sumID]` is an array. it obviously can't have a `name`. (I assume you want `json[sumID][0]` instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this changes, your code will be fine :

```
leagueName = json[sumID][0].name;
leagueTier = json[sumID][0].tier;
leagueDiv  = json[sumID][0].entries[0].division;
leagueLoss = json[sumID][0].entries[0].losses;
leagueWin  = json[sumID][0].entries[0].wins;
```

This is your Formatted JSON Data :

```
{
   "273746":[
      {
         "name":"Darius's Wizards",
         "tier":"GOLD",
         "queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         "entries":[
            {
               "playerOrTeamId":"273746",
               "playerOrTeamName":"Magnanimous",
               "division":"V",
               "leaguePoints":0,
               "wins":19,
               "losses":15,
               "isHotStreak":false,
               "isVeteran":false,
               "isFreshBlood":false,
               "isInactive":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope this will help.